# Realtime auto calculate total value form

Tags: shopify, calculated-field

I'm planning to create a realtime automatic calculating form that gathers the price of products in all (or some) collection and sums up some elements (of course the value is in integer, for example extra fee, modification, ...).

It's Shopify platform, I have created a script that takes the price of a particular product when selected from a dropdown list.

I can't make it do the calculation with some elements also being chosen by the select option.

The idea came from this instruction: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-calculator-script.phtml

Here is the code: the code take price of product works well on my shopify web but when I put it in this code snippet, it doesn't work.

```js
$(function(){
  $('select[name="Menu"]').change(function(){
   var textId= $(this).data('text');
   var price = $( "option:selected" , this).data('price');
   $('#'+textId).val(price);  
  });
 });

 $.fn.fonkTopla = function() {
  var total = 0;
  this.each(function() {
   var deger = fonkDeger($(this).val());
   total += deger;
  });
  return total;
 };


 function fonkDeger(veri) {
  return (veri != '') ? parseInt(veri) : 0;
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name^="inptxt1"]').bind('keyup', function() {
   $('#total').html( $('input[name^="inptxt1"]').fonkTopla());
  });
 });


 function getPrice()
 {
  //Assume form with id="theform"
  var theForm = document.forms["calculate"];
  //Get a reference to the TextBox
  var price = theForm.elements["inptxt1"];
  var howmany =0;
  //If the textbox is not blank
  if(inptxt1.value!="")
  {
   howmany = parseInt(inptxt1.value);
  }
  return howmany;
 }

 var filling_prices= new Array();
 filling_prices["Selection"]=0;
 filling_prices["Fee1"]=3;
 filling_prices["Fee2"]=10;
 
 //This function finds the filling price based on the
 //drop down selection
 function getFillingPrice()
 {
  var optFillingPrice=0;
  //Get a reference to the form id="calculate"
  var theForm = document.forms["calculate"];
  //Get a reference to the select id="filling"
  var selectedFilling = theForm.elements["filling"];

  //set cakeFilling Price equal to value user chose
  //For example filling_prices["Lemon".value] would be equal to 5
  optFillingPrice = filling_prices[selectedFilling.value];

  //finally we return cakeFillingPrice
  return optFillingPrice;
 }

 function getTotal()
 {
  //Here we get the total price by calling our function
  //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
  var lastPrice = getPrice() + getFillingPrice()

  //display the result
  document.getElementById('totalP').innerHTML =
   "Total Price is: "+lastPrice;

 }
```

```html
<form action="" id="calculate">
     <select name="Menu" data-text="inptxt1">
      <option value="0" data-price="0">-- Select --</option>
            <option value="10" data-price="10">10$</option>
            <option value="20" data-price="20">20$</option>
      <!-- this one takes price of product in Shopify collection{% for product in collections.all.products %}
      <option value="{{ product.id }}" data-price="{{ product.price | ceil }}">{{ product.name}}</option>
      {% endfor %}-->
     </select>
     <input type="text" name="inptxt1" id="inptxt1" readonly/> 
     <select id="filling" name='filling' onchange="calculateTotal()">
      <option value="Selection">-- Select --</option>
      <option value="Fee1">Extra fee 1</option>
      <option value="Fee2">Extra fee 2</option>
     </select>
     Total: <div id="totalP"></div>
    </form>
```